# Invalid session token with parse-server, node.js, and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session-cookies, parse-server

I am trying to log in a user from a web site. I am using parse-server hosted at Microsoft Azure. I keep getting the following error, just trying to access the home page:

```
Error handling request: ParseError { code: 209, message: 'invalid session token' } code=209, message=invalid session token
```

And the browser throws a "...redirected you too many times." error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried researching and piecing this together from here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/497 with no luck.

**index.js**

```
var express...
etc...

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});

//Server configuration
...

//Express configuration
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)

// get information from html forms
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/parse', new ParseServer(config.server));
app.use('/parse-dashboard', ParseDashboard(config.dashboard, true));

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: "COOKIE_NAME",
  secret: "COOKIE_SECRET",
  maxAge: 15724800000
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: 'https://localhost:1337/parse/users/me',
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': process.env.APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': process.env.API_KEY,
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': req.session.token
      }
    }).then(function (userData) {
        req.user = Parse.Object.fromJSON(userData.data);
        next();
    }).then(null, function () {
        return res.redirect('/login');
    });
});

app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

//routes
require('./routes/routes.js')(app);


app.listen(process.env.PORT || url.parse(config.server.serverURL).port, function () {
  console.log(`Parse Server running at ${config.server.serverURL}`);
});
```

**routes.js**

```
// app/routes.js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});


module.exports = function(app) {


    // HOME PAGE ========

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs', { title: 'Audiomesh' }); // load the index.ejs file
    });


    // LOGIN ===============================

    // show the login form
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

        res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
    });


    app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
        Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function(user) {
          req.session.user = user;
          req.session.token = user.getSessionToken();
          res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }, function(error) {
          req.session = null;
          res.render('login', { flash: error.message });
        });
  });


    // DASHBOARD =====================

    app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
        res.render('dashboard.ejs', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });


    // LOGOUT ==============================

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

};
```

login.ejs

```
    <body>

      <p><%= message %></p>
      <form name="loginForm" action="/login" method="post">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email"></input>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password"></input>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Log In">
      </form>

        <p>Coming soon azure</p>
        <p>Back to <a href="/">home page</a></p>
    </body>
```

The goal of my web site is for the home page to be an advertising/landing page for the mobile app. So if you're logged in, there's no evidence here. Once you click "Login" then it would check if the user is logged in and either load their dashboard (if true), or the login page (if false).

The problem right now is I can't even load the home page. I get too many redirects.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I'm getting the "too many redirects" error too

Comment: Not yet, I asked one of the commentors in that thread and they weren't sure. I am now trying Mozilla's client-sessions and I'll let you know how that goes.

https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions

Comment: @MayNotBe - I was able to get Client-Sessions to work following that tutorial link I posted. The only issue now is I don't know how to get values from the res.locals.user on the client side. I'm either not doing it right, or the ACL is preventing me from grabbing their info. But at least they're logged in.